# Join large list of Integers into LINQ Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have LINQ query that returns me the following error:
"The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100".

All I need is to count all clients that have BirthDate that I have their ID's in list.
My list of client ID's could be huge (millions of records).

Here is the query:

```
List<int> allClients = GetClientIDs();

int total = context.Clients.Where(x => allClients.Contains(x.ClientID) && x.BirthDate != null).Count();
```

When the query is rewritten this way,

```
int total = context
    .Clients
    .Count(x => allClients.Contains(x.ClientID) && x.BirthDate != null);
```

it causes the same error.

Also tried to make it in different way and it eats all memory:

```
List<int> allClients = GetClientIDs();

total = (from x in allClients.AsQueryable()
         join y in context.Clients
         on x equals y.ClientID
         where y.BirthDate != null
         select x).Count();
```

Comment: Where does `GetClientIDs` get its data from?  If it's pulling it from the db you might want to combine that into your query instead of pulling all the ids to use in a separate query.

Comment: I think it is impossible to do in this form. `allClients.Contains(x.ClientID)` forces query to work locally.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan No, `allClients` can be an `IQueryable` that contains a linq-to-sql query. If so, it would be incorporated as SQL in the `total` query.

Comment: @GertArnold First casting `allClients.AsQueryable()` not guaranty that `allClients` is `IQueryable`. Anyway, even `allClients` is `IQueryable` it not guaranty possibly to translate whole LINQ query to SQL query.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Maybe. But juharr's suggestion is worth the try. Konstantin, if that's impossible I think your only option is to do the query in chunks.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes of course it is very realistic workaround. As another way, you can have helper table in DB in such cases. Then you can add clients id to the table and query `Clients` joining them to helper table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as Gert Arnold mentioned before, making query in chunks solves the problem, but it looks nasty:

```
List<int> allClients = GetClientIDs();

int total = 0;

const int sqlLimit = 2000;

int iterations = allClients.Count() / sqlLimit;

for (int i = 0; i <= iterations; i++)
{
    List<int> tempList = allClients.Skip(i * sqlLimit).Take(sqlLimit).ToList();

    int thisTotal = context.Clients.Count(x => tempList.Contains(x.ClientID) && x.BirthDate != null);

    total = total + thisTotal;
}
```

Comment: What does `GetClientIDs` do?

Comment: It gets client ID's from CSV file

Comment: I guess that means you are pretty limited in your options and chunking your requests is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this same issue at work. The problem is that `list.Contains()` creates a `WHERE column IN (val1, val2, ... valN)` statement, so you're limited to how many values you can put in there. What we ended up doing was in fact do it in batches much like you did.

However, I think I can offer you a cleaner and more elegant piece of code to do this with. Here is an extension method that will be added to the other Linq methods you normally use:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> BulkForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int size = 1000)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < list.Count() / size + 1; index++)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> returnVal = list.Skip(index * size).Take(size).ToList();
        yield return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
foreach (var item in list.BulkForEach())
{
    // Do logic here. item is an IEnumerable<T> (in your case, int)
}
```

---

**EDIT**
Or, if you prefer, you can make it act like the normal List.ForEach() like this:

```
public static void BulkForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<IEnumerable<T>> action, int size = 1000)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < list.Count() / size + 1; index++)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> returnVal = list.Skip(index * size).Take(size).ToList();
        action.Invoke(returnVal);
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
list.BulkForEach(p => { /* Do logic */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been said above, your query is probably being translated to:

```
select count(1)
from Clients
where ClientID = @id1 or ClientID = @id2 -- and so on up to the number of ids returned by GetClientIDs.
```

You will need to change your query such that you aren't passing so many parameters to it.

To see the generated SQL you can set the `Clients.Log = Console.Out` which will cause it to be written to the debug window when it is executed.

EDIT:

A possible alternative to chunking would be to send the IDs to the server as a delimited string, and create a UDF in your database which can covert that string back to a list.

```
var clientIds = string.Jon(",", allClients);

var total = (from client in context.Clients
            join clientIds in context.udf_SplitString(clientIds)
                on client.ClientId equals clientIds.Id
            select client).Count();
```

There are lots of examples on Google for UDFs that split strings.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative and probably the fastest at query time is to add your numbers from the CSV file into a temporary table in your database and then do a join query.

Doing a query in chunks means a lot of round-trips between your client and database. If the list of IDs you are interested in is static or changes rarely, I recommend the approach of a temporary table.

Comment: I have a question about this, actually. Doesn't EF do a round trip per Insert statement? So wouldn't adding 100,000 records to a temporary via EF and then querying for that data be slower than doing 10,000 selects?

Comment: I don't think EntityFramework supports the notion of a temporary table so I was thinking of putting the data onto the server by executing a raw SQL statement, but to answer your question, you're correct, last I checked each insert statement would be a round-trip in EF though some suggestions for EF6 are there to support batch.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind moving the work from the database to the application server and have the memory, try this.

int total = context.Clients.AsEnumerable().Where(x => allClients.Contains(x.ClientID) && x.BirthDate != null).Count();